# In ring theory, what is meant by the notation $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In ring theory, what is meant by the notation $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$?

I have done some research to find that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\{a+b\sqrt{2} : a,b \in \Bbb{Q}\}$, but can't seem to find a consistent definition for the format $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)$.

Comment: It is the smallest field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $\sqrt{2}$ and $i$.

Comment: what is the intuition behind this? I'm struggling to visualise it

Comment: You can think of it as $(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))(i)$ as well; that is, elements of the form $a+b i$, $a, b\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: that makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is the smallest field that contains $\mathbb{Q}$, $\sqrt{2}$ and $i$.

You can prove that it is equal to $\lbrace a + b\sqrt{2} + ic + i\sqrt{2}d \text{ }|\text{ } a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q} \rbrace$.

Answer (score 0):

It is the smallest field extension of $\Bbb Q$ containing $\sqrt{2}$ and $i$.
By the theorem of a primitive element we can again write it as $\Bbb Q(\xi)$ for some primitive element $\xi$. In fact,
it is easy to see that
$$
\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},i)=\Bbb Q(\zeta_8)
$$
the cyclotomic field for  a primitive $8$-th root of unity. The field
degree is $[\Bbb Q(\zeta_8):\Bbb Q]=\varphi(8)=4$.